# I want to use Regex so I can detect everything out of the ASCII code

Tags: javascript, regex

So I'm trying to use some code that someone suggested, but I don't know how to make it work, so far I got this:

```
function Filter(){
    var str = document.getElementById('TArea1').value;
    var res = str.toString();
    var regex = str.replace([^\x20-\x7E]+, "");
    console.log(regex);
    document.getElementById('TArea2').innerHTML = regex;
}
```

As far as I know

```
[^\x20-\x7E]+
```

says that everything out from the Hex code of ASCII characters from 20 to 7E (Which are the elements I want it to ignore) will be detected.

So far this exact code:

```
var regex = str.replace([^\x20-\x7E]+, "");
```

just crashes the components of the page where this is implemented.

Comment: Regex is denoted by two `/` like this `/[^\x20-\x7E]+/`

Comment: Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future. *"As far as I know `[^\x20-\x7E]+` says..."* Actually, it's an array containing one entry to the extent it has meaning, but it should be being reported as a syntax error in your web console ("SyntaxError: Unexpected token `^`"). To make it a regular expression, put `/` around it: `/[^\x20-\x7E]+/`.

Comment: and a `g` for *global*  `/[^\x20-\x7E]+/g`

Comment: Thank you very much everyone! So far it doesn't crash the page anymore, and I'm gonna begin with tests to use it.

Answer (score 0):

So the code that fully answers my Question is below.

```
function Filter(){
    var str = document.getElementById("TArea1").value;
    var regex = new RegExp(/[^\x20-\x7E]+/,"g");
   document.getElementById("TArea2").innerHTML = str;
   var search = str.search(regex);
if(search>=0){
        var bool = true;
    } else {
        var bool = false;
    }
    if(bool){
        document.getElementById("TArea2").innerHTML = str.replace(str, "<span style='background-color:MediumSeaGreen';>"+str+"</span>");
    }
```

Thank you everyone!.